# Unable to fetch data.row in the fields created in popup in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a sample page where I have taken a mat-table which displays the account_data.

When I click on a particular row in the mat-table, the data corresponding to the row items are to be passed to popup component which pops up when a row is clicked on the mat-table.

I am able to fetch the data in the input fields but I'm unable to fetch the data in the mat-form-field input field.

I tried out various ways to fetch the row data for the form-fields also but I don't know what's actually missing..!

Please access my sample app [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-in-angular-vnnwhr?file=app%2Faccountdetail.service.ts)

Any help would be greatly appreciated....!

[image]

Comment: I am not able to seeing any data in table in your sample link

Comment: please check out my updated question .. I have a screen shot of the stackblitz... the data is generated in the table..

Comment: @PareshGami... Is my stackblitz working fine..?

Comment: Something wrong here because i am not able seeing any row

Comment: You are calling localhost api call seeing the console. http://localhost:4200/assets/findAccountData.json

Comment: That was correct for you but not for my machine

Comment: oh yes... should i truncate localhost:4200

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179546/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-heena).